# search and replace within specific htaccess files - linux

Tags: linux, .htaccess, sed

I need to add this line to every .htaccess file that is located in a `/home/*/site/assets/.htaccess` 
where * can be any amount of directories deep

I need to find this text

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/assets/sym/$1 [L,NS]
```

and add a line above it, or replace it with this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/assets/sym
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/assets/sym/$1 [L,NS]
```

I've looked online at this [site](http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Find_and%20Replace_with_Sed.html) but I am unclear how to deal with

1. generating a list of the files I want to edit (so find all files that match this path: /home/*/site/assets/.htaccess)
2. Adding line breaks in the replace text

Can anyone suggest a resource that will clearly explain it, or fail that, let me know if I am looking at the correct tools for this job?

My OS is Cent OS 5.5, i'm running a LAMP server if that makes much difference, apache 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Something like that:

```
for dir in `find /home -type d | grep 'site/assets'`
do
    htaccess="$dir/.htacess";
    sed -ibak -e 's@RewriteRule \^\(.*\)\$ /site/assets/sym/\$1 \[L,NS\]@RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/assets/sym\n\0@' $htaccess
done
```

On my box:

```
sed -e 's@RewriteRule \^\(.*\)\$ /site/assets/sym/\$1 \[L,NS\]@RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/assets/sym\n\0@' test
Foobarlol

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/assets/sym
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/assets/sym/$1 [L,NS]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/assets/test/$1 [L,NS]

Bleh
```

with `test`

```
Foobarlol

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/assets/sym/$1 [L,NS]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/assets/test/$1 [L,NS]

Bleh
```

Comment: Useless Use of Ls in Backticks http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html - you mean `for dir in /home/*` plain and simple.

Comment: ... but this also fails to find subdirectories. You need `find` to recurse.

Comment: @tripleee useless, I'm not sure because I don't want any file sitting in home just directories and for sub-directories, I misread the OP. Thanks for the point.

Comment: Read the link, it's a common shell programming antipattern. The way you changed it to find in backticks is also discussed on the page, although in this particular case I would regard it as benign.

Comment: ... and note that `ls -ld` will list regular files as well, it will just not list directory contents if given a directory as argument.